# How to escape characters in javascript with a space before

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I would like to escape a " /" (a slash with a **space before**) in a javascript expression.

Naturally, it works with this expression:

```
string.replace(/\//g,"\n");
```

It replaces all the **"/"**-s in my string with a **"\n"** (console linebreak).

But what I really need is an expression, or a method to replace **" /"-s** instead of **"/"-s**.

*As You may know, unfortunatelly the escaping expression breaks this way:*

```
string.replace(/\ //g,"\n");
```

Thanks for Your help!

Comment: You need to have the space before the escape `/ \//`

Comment: It seems you are not very familiar with the purpose of the escape character (``\``). You have to escape every character that otherwise has a special purpose. In this case, the slash denotes the end of the regular expression literal. If you want your expression to literally contain the `/` character, then you have to escape it so that it is *not* treated as the end of the literal. A space on the other hand does not have a special meaning inside a regular expression, hence it does not have to be escaped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need:

```
string.replace(/ \//g,"\n");
```

so that you're matching a space followed by an (escaped) forward slash.

This has some good examples: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
string.replace(/\s\//g,"\n");
```